# My xcode project doesn't add me a .png image

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I was trying to add new images into my xcode project in order to make my app universal, adding images for iphone. When compiling, this is the error:

```
2013-02-26 08:58:35.585 XXXX[2132:707] cocos2d: Couldn't add XXXX-XXX.png in CCTextureCache
2013-02-26 08:58:35.598 XXXXX[2132:707] *** Assertion failure in -[MainMenuLayer addChild:], /Users/XXXX/XXXXX/XXXXX/XXXXX/XXXX/cocos2d/CCNode.m:362
2013-02-26 08:58:35.632 XXXXXX[2132:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Argument must be non-nil'

*** First throw call stack:
(0x336c68bf 0x301ba1e5 0x336c67b9 0x30f0d3b3 0x4abef 0xf6495 0x49279 0xcbc8d 0x49279 0xca7cd 0x6413d 0x6bd6b 0x98ff9 0x9a39b 0x34dab423 0x34dab379 0x31940f93 0x36c46891 0x3368ff43 0x3369a553 0x3369a4f5 0x33699343 0x3361c4dd 0x3361c3a5 0x37d8efcd 0x3107f743 0xc90fb 0x3df8)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

someone knows what happens?

Comment: They don't look like compilation errors, they look like runtime errors.

Comment: Yes, you are right... maybe is calling a different image.

Comment: Add a symbolic breakpoint on `objc_exception_throw`, run the app in the debugger and start digging.

Comment: +1 @trojanfoe. You might have to debug your code a little more

Answer (score 0):

The file name you specified is more than likely not the same as the actual filename. You will see this error if you try adding a file that xcode cannot find. Double check the file names and make sure that you have:

1. added the file to your project (File->Add Files to xxxx)
2. The file name of the file added is exactly the same as the file you
   are trying to add to MainMenulayer (It is case sensitive)
3. You have also included the file extension (.png) in the code used to add the png to
   MainMenuLayer